# sending json from one logstash to another

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

i have 3 node setup

10.x.x.1 - application and filebeat
10.x.x.2 - machine for parsing and logstash
10.x.x.3 - having centralized logstash node from where we need to push messages into Elastic Search

in 10.x.x.2 when i set the output codec to stdout , i can see the messages coming from 10.x.x.1.

Now, i need to forward all the json messages from 10.x.x.2 to 10.x.x.3 . I tried using TCP. But the messages are not gettting sent.

10.x.x.2 logstash conf file

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5045
  }
}


output{
#stdout { codec => rubydebug }
tcp{
host => "10.x.x.3"
port => 3389
}
```

10.x.x.3 logstash conf file

```
input{
tcp{
host => "10.x.x.3"
port => 3389
#mode => "server"
#codec => "json"
}
}

output{
stdout{ codec => rubydebug }
}
```

is there any plugin which can send json data from one logstash to another logstash server

Comment: TCP is tricky to work as output for json, because of possible newline characters at your json output. A good way to do what you need is using Gelf output (as it generates a valid json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config should work.

But you have to be carreful with the "codec" properties.

Try first to set it to "line" on the output **AND** the input plugins of the two logstash.

And see if log are incoming.

With the codec set to "line" you will have logicly no problem to forward the logs.

Then work on the "json" properties.

Do not forget that you can activate the debug mode of logstash with the argument --debug and you can log with the arguments : -l logFileName

When you start to work with the codec json look for "_jsonparsefailure" tags, which could explain why it do not transfert logs between the two logstash.